# How to update an ecs service with specific tag version?

Tags: shell, amazon-ecs, amazon-ecr

I'm trying to update an ecs fargate service that has multiple tags associated with the given ecr container image that's used by the service's task definition.

The container image in ecr has the following tags: 2023.3.0-latest, test

As you can see, this is just includes a version tag and then an environment tag, which in this case is just, "test".

In the task definition I have the ecr url passed in using the standard format: <baseurl>/<ecrrepo>:test

What I want to do is when there is an update on that specific service associated with the task definition to use the specific image associated with the specific version and environment.

For example, how would I update the service with the specific task definition of another image which was also for test but which has a different version?

So far I've got a number of Jenkins jobs running which have accomplished everything up to the point of filtering on the version and updating the service associated with the specific environment. What I've got working is as follows:

1. Create repo, upload container to ecr with the specified version, tag with the associated with the specified version, and push the container image to ecr.
2. Retag the image with the specified environment, in this case, "test"

The third step would be how to update the task with that specific container image associated with the version and environment.

So say, for example, I force update the task associated with the "test" tag, how do I first filter on the specific version of the "test" tag so that ecs knows which version of "test" to use?

Comment: It seems like you're confusing some terminologies or relationships between things... ECS _services_ are associated with one _task definition family_. Tasks will specify exactly one _task definition revision_ (a specific task definition version). Each task definition version will specify one or more containers and each container will specify an _image_ to use to create the container. Typically you (1) create a new task definition revision and then (2) update a service to use the new revision, which will cause a deployment of new tasks using the revision you specified (and remove the old tasks).

Comment: This is a use case that goes beyond a simplistic update a task with one tag. There can be multiple tags associated with an ecr image, not just one. The task definition family would not change, nor in the use case I am referring to above, the env tag at the end, which is just "test". What I am asking is how to update an existing task definition with an ecr image that has multiple tags, one which is immutable and set as the image in the task (in this case, "test"), and another which is rolling (in this case, the specific version of the "test" container -> 2023.1.0-latest).

Comment: Task definition revisions are immutable. You must create a new task definition revision then update the service to use the new revision. Your task definition should only specify **unique versioned tags that never change**. Never use tags that can point to different images at different points in time in your task definition (for example, `latest`). Otherwise, what image your tasks run is not deterministic and a lot of issues can arise... You can create a new revision by describing an existing one and just changing the `image` value (and deleting certain keys that can't be used in creation).

Comment: `how do I first filter on the specific version of the "test" tag so that ecs knows which version of "test" to use?` doesn't make sense to me because a tag can only point to one specific image at a time. When ECS starts the container (for any reason) it will use whatever `test` is _currently_ pointing to. (which is why you should only use tags that never change in your task definition)

Comment: You're not understanding what Im asking for the use case or your concern about the side effects is hindering you from stating it can be done which is all Im trying to say.

Comment: @stonewalker747 Your use case is no different from other use casees I've ever seen with ECS. You keep saying it is some special scenario but it is exactly the same as almost every other ECS deployment I've ever worked on.

Comment: Thanks for the insight. If you’re upset then I know I’ve done something right which is not following what you say.

Answer (score 3):

A couple important things:

- Task definitions are the **only** place where you can define what image should be used by containers in a task.
- Task definition revisions are immutable -- they cannot be changed after they are created.
- Your task definitions should generally ONLY specify images with **unique image tags that never change**. Otherwise, your tasks will have indeterministic and inconsistent behavior.
- To update the image your service tasks use, you **must** create a new task definition revision and update the service to use the new revision.
- You probably only want to move your environment tag on the image *after* updating the service, not before.

Your basic steps should look something like this:

1. Build the image(s) and push the image(s) to ECR with a unique tag
2. Create a new task definition revision that specifies the unique tag for the appropriate container(s)
3. Update the service to use the new revision
4. (optionally) wait for service stabilization
5. Upon successful update, retag the environment

A script to do all this might look *something* like this:

```
# 1. Build the image(s) and push the image(s) to ECR with a unique tag
unique_tag="$BUILD_TAG" # or whatever you want that is unique
new_image="<ecr repo>:$unique_tag"
service_arn="<service ARN>"

env_name="test" # or whatever
cache_image="<ecr repo>:$env_name"

# leverage docker cache from the currently active image in this environment, if it exists
docker pull $cache_image || echo "no cache"
docker build --cache-from "$cache_image" -t <ECR repo>:$unique_tag .
docer push <ECR repo>:$unique-tag .

# 2. Create a new task definition revision

# here we assume you don't store the task definition JSON in the repo, which means we need to get it from API call
# by default, this gets the latest ACTIVE revision, which is usually what you want.
existing_taskdef="$(aws ecs describe-task-definition --task-definition=<your-taskdef-family-name>)"

# create new taskdef using jq to replace the image key in the first container (we assume only one container `.containerDefinitions[0]` is defined in this example)
# describe-task-definition returns some keys that can't be used with register-task-defintiion, so we delete those, too
new_task_definition="$(jq --arg IMAGE "$new_image" '.taskDefinition | .containerDefinitions[0].image = $IMAGE | del(.taskDefinitionArn) | del(.revision) | del(.status) | del(.requiresAttributes) | del(.compatibilities)' <<< "$existing_taskdef")"

# register the new revision
new_revision_arn="$(aws ecs register-task-definition --cli-input-json "$new_taskdefinition" --output text --query 'taskDefinition.taskDefinitionArn')"


# 3. Update the service to use the new revision

aws ecs update-service --service="$service_arn" --task-definition="$new_revision_arn"

# 4. wait for deployment stabilization (omitted for brevity)

# 5 retag the environment

# in subsequent workflows, the newly built image will be used for the cache
docker tag "$new_image" "<ecr repo>:${env_name}"
docker push "<ecr repo>:${env_name}"
```

Comment: Yes, I've got most of that listed above. The use case is more complicated. I was trying to find a way to do this without creating a new task definition. The idea behind keeping the "test" tag in the container definition of a given task revision was so that I could filter on the tags. There's no way to pass in a specific digest to the update service command via aws cli from what I'm seeing.

Comment: @stonewalker747 you can't. Task definition revisions cannot be changed after they are created. You **must** create a new one. Updating the task definition revision used by the service is the only reliable way to change what the service tasks run. The container definition in the task definition is what ECS uses to start the container. Therefore, to change the image used by a service, you must change the task definition revision containing a the new `image` in the container definition. Every running task is associated with exactly one task definition revision.

Comment: @stonewalker747 you would use the specific digest in the task definition, instead of the image tag, if you want to use specific image digests instead of tags. As sytech has said multiple times now, you will absolutely have to update the task definition, either with the image tag or digest. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/task_definition_parameters.html#container_definition_image

Comment: @MarkB I think there's been some confusion over the use case. I've updated a solution below that's working with what I was needing. I didn't have to create a new task definition, just needed to retag the version and then update the other tag env tag accordingly. Now it works with the versions and I can reuse the existing revision the same task definition.

Comment: @stonewalker747 You are ignoring the warning about moving image tags. ECS doesn't handle that well. What happens if ECS has a previous version of an image with that tag cached? There is nothing telling ECS that it needs to go get the new version.

Answer (score -2):

Found a working solution. Again the use case was if you have multiple versions of an image in ecr that you're wanting to deploy via ecs fargate, and you dont want to create *separate* task definitions for each, but keep the image set to "test", and just update the version each time.

Contrary to some opinions, this can be done. When you retag the version you're wanting with "test" (i.e., 2023.1.0 or 2023.2.0) ecr updates that tag to the version specified and removes the tag from the previous version specified. In other words, if you refresh ecr you'll see the "test" tag, or whatever other tag you specified, switched to that version  (NOTE: I've hardcoded the version below for simplicity's sake).

```
1. Push the tagged image to ECR

docker load < containername:2023.1.0-latest.tar.gz

SERVICE_NAME="ecsServiceName"
ACCOUNT_ID=$(aws sts get-caller-identity --query Account --output text)
ECR_URL="$ACCOUNT_ID.dkr.ecr.<region>.amazonaws.com/SERVICE_NAME:2023.1.0-latest"
    
aws ecr create-repository --repository-name ${SERVICE_NAME:?} --region <region> || true

docker tag containername:2023.1.0-latest $ECR_URL
 
$(aws ecr get-login --region <region> --no-include-email --registry-ids $ACCOUNT_ID)
 
docker push $ECR_URL
    
2. Retag the image with env tag

MY_MANIFEST=$(aws ecr batch-get-image --repository-name $SERVICE_NAME --image-ids imageTag=2023.1.0-latest --region <region> --query images[].imageManifest --output text)

aws ecr put-image --repository-name $SERVICE_NAME --image-tag test --image-manifest "$MY_MANIFEST" --region <region>

3. Update the service with the task definition

aws ecs update-service --cluster ecsClusterName --service $SERVICE_NAME --task-definition ecsTaskDefinitionName --force-new-deployment --region <region>
```

Comment: As mentioned in the other answer: "Your task definitions should generally ONLY specify images with unique image tags that never change. Otherwise, your tasks will have indeterministic and inconsistent behavior." You are current using a tag that changes which image it is pointing at, so over time you will find that your deployments are indeterministic and exhibit inconsistent behavior.

Comment: Again this is a specific use case. I didn't say I was parading this as a canonical best practice to be used every time. For this use case, this is working, which is half the battle; the other half being people saying it "can't" be done.

Comment: Imagine: what happens when the forced deployment fails? What happens if you push the image tag change, but your current deployment creates a new task for any reason (replacing unhealthy tasks, scaling up, replacing underlying EC2 instances, etc.) -- your service will have indeterminate versions of images running in your tasks. You'll end up making unintentional changes to your environment. You can end up with one version of an image in one task, but a newer version in another, even within the same deployment/taskdef. It's not just a violation of best-practice, it's a disaster waiting to happen

Comment: @stonewalker747 you say it's working, but systech and myself have both seen deployments start to fail, or exhibit strange behavior over time, when doing docker image tagging this way. We are just trying to warn you that this will eventually fail.

Comment: As mentioned above, I'm using ecs fargate, not ecs ec2. Besides that, though, the whole point of having versions is to test stuff out. Reverting to other versions is part of the development process. Additionally if a task fails, ecs reverts to the previous container deployment which was working. If a new task is created, that's not really a major deal. You can stop the old task and create a new one from one that was working, etc.

Comment: `Additionally if a task fails, ecs reverts to the previous container deployment which was working` but if your task definition specifies an image whose tag points to a different image, it will use the new image you tagged, not the old one that worked (therein lies one of the problems with using such tags). You will have to move the tag back to the working image then reap all your tasks again. But if you just created a new taskdef with unique tags, ECS could handle all that for you...

Comment: Imagine: What happens if you have 20 versions of the same container to deploy in three different ecs clusters? Maintaining all those images and keeping track of those versions is costly and time consuming.

Comment: Nobody said it couldn't be done this way. It was already described in the other answer as a way you could do things, but that it would cause issues down the road if you do it that way.

Comment: "What happens if you have 20 versions of the same container to deploy in three different ecs clusters? Maintaining all those images and keeping track of those versions is costly and time consuming." No, that's what your CI/CD platform should be keeping track of for you automatically, and ECS should be keeping track of the previous version so it can perform rollbacks. By doing it the way you are now, you are preventing your CI/CD platform, and ECS, from keeping track of anything and deployment rollbacks will no longer work.

Comment: Similarly, nobody said this was "the" way to go about ecs fargate deployments. It was stated that this was a specific use case for when you have to consider whether or not you want to have a hundred or so separate task revisions running at a given time for each version or find a way to simplify things.